# Trouble connecting to ethernet in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, ethernet

I bought an HP 6-th Gen laptop recently and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. I know this question has been asked before but I really can't get my ethernet working.
I am unable to download the r8168-dkms package also.
Please help.
When i give the command

```
ifconfig -a -v
```

it shows

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:b6:86:bc:a8:79  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:212904 errors:0 dropped:30073 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1441 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:13059817 (13.0 MB)  TX bytes:333485 (333.4 KB)

enp0s20f0u2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:4d:df:e6:63:97  
      inet addr:192.168.42.236  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a4b:fad8:4fab:9e01/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2402:3a80:a7b:6182:2d9:cf5d:bf22:f658/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2402:3a80:a7b:6182:9832:14b9:656b:3244/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:29222 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:28902 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:39714108 (39.7 MB)  TX bytes:4349461 (4.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:61303 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:61303 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4637550 (4.6 MB)  TX bytes:4637550 (4.6 MB)
```

Comment: You need to put additional information such as what connection you are trying (wired or wireless).  What network hardware you have.  You can start by copying the output of `ifconfig -a -v` into your question.

Comment: Your ethernet appears to be connected. It has an IP address and is up. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: This ethernet connection is actually my Redmi note 4 tethered to the laptop. I am not getting any connection in case of my broadband(Alliance)